# Verify data in `for` loop

Tags: javascript

I have an array with strings and I have a string - `snowy` for example. The task is to verify if the `snowy` is in `arr`, if `yes`, push it into one array, if `no`, push it into another. I am not sure that use of `if(true)` is correct way.

```
const arr = ["sunny", "rainy", "cloudy", "foggy"];

if (true) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === "snowy") {
      someArr.push("snowy");
      // some other conditions
    }
  }
  anotherArr.push("snowy");
  // some other conditions
}
```

Comment: `if (true)` is pointless, since it will always evaluate to `true`, so the `if` statement will always run. Under this condition there's no point having the `if`.

Comment: Why not just `if (arr.includes('snowy')) { someArr.push('snowy') } else { anotherArr.push('snowy') }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
    const arr = ["sunny", "rainy", "cloudy", "foggy" ]

    if(arr.includes("snowy")){
        someArr.push("snowy");
    }else{
        anotherArr.push("snowy");
    }
```

In this case you are not going to need the for loop because the inludes() function looks for the string in the complete array. Here you have some tutorial of how to use the includes() function.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try with `some`

```js
const arr = ["sunny", "rainy", "cloudy", "foggy"];

const someArray = [];
const anotherArray = [];

if (arr.some((item) => item === "snowy")) {
  someArray.push("snowy");
} else {
  anotherArray.push("snowy");
}

console.log({ someArray, anotherArray });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = ["sunny", "rainy", "cloudy", "foggy"];
const set = new Set(arr);
const someArr = []
const anotherArr = []
  
 set.has(data = "sunny") ? someArr.push(data) : anotherArr.push(data)
 
 console.log(someArr)
 
 console.log(anotherArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.includes()` in the `arr` to check if the value you are looking for exists and use the returned value in a condition

```
const arr = ['sunny', 'rainy', 'cloudy', 'foggy'];
const someArr = [];
const anotherArr = [];

const hasSnowy = arr.includes('snowy');
console.log(hasSnowy); // false

if (hasSnowy) {
  someArr.push('snowy');
} else {
  anotherArr.push('snowy');
}
```